# Web client to view/add/modify/delete column family in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Is there any web client to view/add/modify/delete column family in cassandra. 
I mean like how there is toad for Oracle, SQLyog for MYSql.
Also, please provide JAVA and Python API for accessing data from/to Cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataStax Community Edition includes OpsCenter - a web-client for Cassandra. It supports viewing/adding/deleting/modifying keyspaces and column families as well as monitoring of  clusters.

It is free and you can download it [here](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter).

Answer (score 2):

@DevP

There is a DataStax Developer Tools, which is a visual client to query data from Cassandra, download **[here](http://www.datastax.com/download/clientdrivers)**

Comment: Is there a DataStax Developer tool for linux. I could see for mac & win. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking phpmyadmin then you are after [cassui](https://code.google.com/p/cassui/), its a java based web app that allows for CRUD operations.